# Django admin, multiple inlines, related to parent and each other, cannot save the objects toghether

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I am creating devices network management using django admin, (Django==2.2), where for 1 device can be attached multiple mac addresses and for the same device can be attached multiple ips, but at the same time ips are attached to mac asdresses, and I need to chanage/add/view them toghether.

For the device view I have no problems, there is all displayed, the problem is at add/change the device, need there also to add/change new mac/ip.

```
###From models
#Device class, without others not important parameters
class Devices(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    ...........

    def __str__(self):
        return format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        managed = False
        db_table = 'devices'
        verbose_name_plural = "Devices"

#Macs class
class Macs(models.Model):
    mac = models.CharField(max_length=17, validators=[validate_mac_adress])
    device = models.ForeignKey('Devices', related_name="Macs", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...........

    def __str__(self):
        return format(self.mac)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'macs'

#Ips class
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=15, validators=[validate_ipv4])
    device = models.ForeignKey('Devices', related_name="Ips", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mac = models.ForeignKey('Macs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return format(self.ip)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ips'

#form for inline
class IpsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ips
        exclude = ('mac',)



#####from admin.py

class MACInline(admin.TabularInline): 
    model = Macs
    extra = 0

class IPSInline(admin.TabularInline): 
    title = 'IPS'
    model = Ips
    form = IpsForm
    extra = 0

    def save(self, *ags, **kwargs):
        self.ip.mac_id = self.mac.id
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class DeviceAdmin(......):
     .......
     inlines = MACInline, IPSInline,
     .......
```

At the moment I have a nice form for add a new device, with mac inline field and Ip inline field, where I excluded the mac adress, because it is a ForeignKey and I can't add there new mac address, I can choose only from existing one.

So, I can add device and mac adress, (mac is related only to device),
But, I have the problem for adding there an ip, because it is related to mac and device.

I am getting error: "Column 'mac_id' cannont be null")

How can I correctly edit the IPSInline save_model, so this will can get the mac_id from the basically last saved mac, on the same add form?

(by the way, the mac is getting saved, even if I get this error)

Comment: Hey, your foreign key is not nullable so you will have to link the mac before saving your instance, what about a custom char field in your form? You could create a mac instance with the field value in the form save function.

Comment: I have tried this one way to, but in this case I have 2 problems:
1) I will get error:  "Column 'device_id' cannont be null"), because it is related to device as well as for ip
2) If I use this cleared form for mac in IPInline, I will not get pre populated mac, at the change device form, so I don't know what is the mac, already assigned to it

`def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
mac = form.cleaned_data["mac",]
mac, _ = Macs.objects.get_or_create(mac=mac)
obj.mac = mac
super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)`
this is what I tried

Comment: Okey let's do something. Tell me what is the ideal way of creating these objects with forms. Without thinking about limitations. Just like if you create them in paper.